# Appending list of key:value pairs without adding more curly braces in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I need to append a list of key:value pairs multiple times. However, this produces additional curly braces after each .append().

Basically, I have something like this:

```
textToDump = {"food": "cereal_bowl",
                      "ingredients":[]}
    
textToDump["ingredients"].append({"milk": 100,
                                 "cereal": 100,
                                 })
textToDump["ingredients"].append({"honey": 10})
print(textToDump)
```

which results in:

```
{'food': 'cereal_bowl', 'ingredients': [{'milk': 100, 'cereal': 100}, {'honey': 10}]}
```

what I need is:

```
{'food': 'cereal_bowl', 'ingredients': [{'milk': 100, 'cereal': 100, 'honey': 10]}
```

I also tried using dictionary+.update() instead of list. However, I need to be able to have duplicate entries in my structure ("ingredients"). What would be the simplest way of achieving this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say you want to be able to have duplicate entries in your ingredients dictionary, what do you mean? If you mean like this `{'milk':100,'cereal':80,'milk':20}`, that's sadly impossible, as dictionaries are a mapping of keys to values - each key must map to exactly 1 value. Depending on how you're using it, a data structure like this might work: `{'milk':[100,20],'cereal':[80]}`. Sorry if I'm not understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
textToDump = {"food": "cereal_bowl", "ingredients": []}

textToDump["ingredients"].append(
    {
        "milk": 100,
        "cereal": 100,
    }
)
textToDump["ingredients"][0].update({"honey": 10})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
textToDump = {"food": "cereal_bowl",
                      "ingredients":[]}
    
textToDump["ingredients"].append({"milk": 100,
                                 "cereal": 100,
                                 })
if textToDump["ingredients"]:
    textToDump["ingredients"][0].update({"honey": 10})

print(textToDump)
```

output:

```
{
  "food": "cereal_bowl",
  "ingredients": [
    {
      "milk": 100,
      "cereal": 100,
      "honey": 10
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You desired output says you need a list that has only single dictionary item. So add your first dictionary like before(by `.append`ing), then for the next dictionaries, you need to grab the first dictionary and update it:

```py
textToDump["ingredients"].append({"milk": 100, "cereal": 100})
textToDump["ingredients"][0].update({"honey": 10})
```

However I don't think you need a list here. Why not just having a dictionary for ingredients?

```py
textToDump = {"food": "cereal_bowl", "ingredients": {}}

textToDump["ingredients"].update({"milk": 100, "cereal": 100})
textToDump["ingredients"].update({"honey": 10})
textToDump["ingredients"]["something-else"] = 20
```

In case these dictionaries come separately and they are have overlapped keys, I would suggest using `collections.Counter` object. You can then easily use its `.update` method:

```py
from collections import Counter
textToDump = {"food": "cereal_bowl", "ingredients": Counter()}

textToDump["ingredients"].update({"milk": 100, "cereal": 100})
textToDump["ingredients"].update({"milk": 10})
print(textToDump)
```

Comment: I actually need duplicate items in my real code. However, your (and others) solution of using textToDump["ingredients"][0].update({"honey": 10}) works perfectly. Thanks .

Comment: @Andrej Those solutions do not work. If you add duplicates, they will overwrite the existing entries.

Comment: @ekhumoro Yes right but do we need duplicate ingredients ? If we need to add something in different steps, we can update its value. To me its a bit non-sense. In future if we want to get an ingredient we have to iterate through dictionaries and sum up the values of a same keys.

Comment: @S.B The OP says they need duplicate items. What exactly that means is unclear, since they don't give sufficient details about the source of the data, nor how the duplicates are to be handled. Should the values be summed, listed, counted, overwritten - or what exactly? I think it's only fair to point this out to the OP, since their comment above seems a bit self-contradictory.